# Jupyter notebook view missing in Spyder ide even after install

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, spyder

Help, I am trying to use jupyter notebook in spyder , I've already installed the jupyter plugin via `conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide` upon installation I restarted jupyter but the `notebook` tab is missing under the `view` tab in spyder.

Message of installation of notebook:
[image]

Screenshot of my views and panel tabs in `spyder`:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately,

> The Spyder notebook plugin is not yet compatible with Spyder 5 [...]. The latest version of spyder-notebook is compatible with Spyder 4.2[...]

See [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/issues/362#issuecomment-828737990). So either you can revert to Spyder 4.2 or wait for a solution. The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/issues/360#issue-855896210).